# An easy way to calculate those limits?

Tags: calculus

The following real numbers sequences  $\left(a_n\right)_{n\ge 0},\:\left(b_n\right)_{n\ge 0},\:\left(c_n\right)_{n\ge \:0},\:\left(d_n\right)_{n\ge \:0} $  have the property : $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(a^2_n+b^2_n+c^2_n+d^2_n-a_nb_n-b_nc_n-c_nd_n-d_n\right)=-\frac{2}{5}$ . If $a=\:\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(a_n\right)\:,\:b=\:\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}\left(b_n\right)\:,\:c=\:\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}\left(c_n\right)\:,\:d=\:\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}\left(d_n\right)$, then the value of the sum a+b+c+d is : a) 1 , b)3/2 c)9/5 d)2  e)12/5 f)5/2??

I am getting stuck somewhere when i am trying to calculate each limit , i was looking to see if there is an easier way to do it . Thank you !

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer the question. All we know is $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-ab-bc-cd-d=-\frac25$$  This certainly doesn't determine $a+b++c+d$ uniquely.  Have you left something out or made some sort of typo?

Comment: The only thing that i left out is that sequences are of real numbers and that is all .

Comment: Well, $a=b=c=0,\, d=\frac25$ satisfies the hypotheses, but $a+b+c+d=\frac25$ isn't one of the possible answers.  There are infinitely many other possibilities.  There's something wrong with the question.

Comment: Maybe i am typing it  wrong , because this is actually a translation of the original text . I've checked multiple times and this is how it is written ....

Comment: @saluspatz $a=b=c=0,d=2/5$ does **not** satisfy the hypothesis, because the limit is then $\frac{4}{25}-\frac{2}{5}=-\frac{6}{25}$, which is not equal to $-\frac{2}{5}$. Even if there are infinitely many other possibilities, it could be the case that only one of the six possible options is possible, so the problem may be solvable even without uniqueness.

Comment: Isn't f) 2/5?. 5/2 seems out

Comment: No, I've checked it again, it is 5/2 .